# Raspbian support for TLS 1.3

Tags: networking, raspbian-stretch

Are there or will there be packages available to support TLS 1.3 on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)? For example OpenSSL 1.1.1{,x} or even 3.x?

Comment: You're unlikely to get that before Raspbian Buster gets released due to the way Raspbian follows DebIan and DebIan doesn't like to introduce new stuff except on a version to version upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found out in my research, and also the comment suggests:

At the moment there is no way of getting openssl 1.1.1 to Raspian Stretch and I have wait for the next release, Raspian Buster.

Thank you for confirming that.

Answer (score 3):

For those who don't mind manually upgrading to OpenSSL 1.1.1 (or later version 3.1) in Raspbian, there is easy way of doing so in Unix system:

- (Optionally) Remove previous OpenSSL by running `apt-get remove openssl`
- Download the entire OpenSSL source code from its [official Github repository](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) by running `git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git`
- Go to the downloaded openssl folder,
- Check the latest release version by running `git tag`  and `git rev-parse <TAG_NAME>`, the `git rev-parse` will show the commit ID of the tag name. Then roll back to that version by `git checkout <COMMIT_ID>` (In the case here, the version is 1.1.1c).
- Open the file named `INSTALL`, simply follow the steps described in [**Quick Start**](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL#L76) of `INSTALL`. For example here are all the steps in Unix system (Note that `make` and `make test` take few hours to complete) :

```
./config  --prefix=/PATH/TO/INSTALLED
make
make test
make install
```

- `--prefix` is optional if you install OpenSSL to non-default path.
- Modify and refresh the link files `libssl.so.1.1` , `libcrypto.so.1.1` in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/` (commands shown below).

  - Because the openssl libraries we manually built are copied to `/usr/local/lib` (by previous `make install`), while installation from package management tool like `apt-get` will copy the pre-built libraries to different folder (which is `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/` in Raspbian).
  - For OpenSSL 3.x, the libraries name should be `libssl.so.3` , `libcrypto.so.3`

```
// if you don't modify the links as mentioned above, you'll get linking error as shown below :
openssl: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by openssl)
openssl: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by openssl)
```

```
// modify & refresh library links
cd  /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
sudo unlink libssl.so.1.1
sudo unlink libcrypto.so.1.1
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1      libssl.so.1.1
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1   libcrypto.so.1.1
sudo ldconfig
```

After steps above, you can check your openssl version again:

```
openssl version
> OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
```

I also built MQTT message server/client with this openSSL v1.1.1, run the MQTT server/client, and debug/capture packets using wireshark, it works well & TLS v1.3 can be enabled for sure.

Answer (score -2):

apt-cache search shows many openssl packages.

```
$ apt-cache search openssl

acme-tiny - letsencrypt tiny Python client
aolserver4-nsopenssl - AOLserver 4 module: module for SSL mode
apache2-ssl-dev - Apache HTTP Server (mod_ssl development headers)
bruteforce-salted-openssl - try to find the passphrase for files encrypted with OpenSSL
cl-plus-ssl - Common Lisp interface to OpenSSL
cryptmount - Management of encrypted file systems
dehydrated - ACME client implemented in Bash
dlang-openssl - D version of the C headers for openssl
erlang-crypto - Erlang/OTP cryptographic modules
erlang-p1-fast-tls - native TLS / SSL driver for Erlang / Elixir
erlang-p1-tls - native TLS / SSL driver for Erlang / Elixir
forensics-all - Debian Forensics Environment - essential components (metapackage)
fp-units-net - Free Pascal - networking units dependency package
fp-units-net-3.0.0 - Free Pascal - networking units
gambas3-gb-openssl - Gambas OpenSSL component
gjots2 - Simple jotter (outline processor) for X11/gtk-gnome
globus-gsi-cert-utils-progs - Globus Toolkit - Globus GSI Cert Utils Library Programs
heartbleeder - test servers for OpenSSL CVE-2014-0160 aka Heartbleed
hiera-eyaml - OpenSSL Encryption backend for Hiera
jruby-openssl - Ruby library that emulates the OpenSSL native library for JRuby
kamailio-tls-modules - contains the TLS kamailio transport module
keyringer - Distributed secret management using GnuPG and Git
lcmaps-openssl-interface - LCMAPS header files for OpenSSL interfaces
letsencrypt.sh - ACME client - transitional dummy package to dehydrated
libace-ssl-6.3.3 - ACE secure socket layer library
libapache2-mod-gnutls - Apache module for SSL and TLS encryption with GnuTLS
libapache2-mod-php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
libbellesip-dbg - SIP stack from Linphone team (debugging symbols)
libbellesip-dev - SIP stack from the Linphone team (development files)
libbellesip0 - SIP stack from the Linphone team
libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl - Perl module to access OpenSSL multiprecision integer arithmetic libraries
libcrypt-openssl-dsa-perl - module which implements the DSA signature verification system
libcrypt-openssl-pkcs10-perl - Perl extension to OpenSSL's PKCS10 API
libcrypt-openssl-pkcs12-perl - Perl extension to OpenSSL's PKCS12 API
libcrypt-openssl-random-perl - module to access the OpenSSL pseudo-random number generator
libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl - module for RSA encryption using OpenSSL
libcrypt-openssl-x509-perl - Perl extension to OpenSSL's X509 API
libcrypt-ssleay-perl - OpenSSL support for LWP
libcurl3 - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
libcurl3-dbg - debugging symbols for libcurl (OpenSSL, GnuTLS and NSS flavours)
libcurl4-openssl-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavour)
libengine-pkcs11-openssl - OpenSSL engine for PKCS#11 modules
libengine-pkcs11-openssl1.1 - OpenSSL 1.1 engine for PKCS#11 modules
libevent-openssl-2.0-5 - Asynchronous event notification library (openssl)
libghc-cipher-aes-dev - Fast AES cipher implementation
libghc-cipher-aes-doc - Fast AES cipher implementation; documentation
libghc-cipher-aes-prof - Fast AES cipher implementation; profiling libraries
libghc-hookup-dev - abstraction over network connections with SOCKS5 and TLS
libghc-hookup-doc - abstraction over network connections with SOCKS5 and TLS; documentation
libghc-hookup-prof - abstraction over network connections with SOCKS5 and TLS; profiling libraries
libghc-hsopenssl-dev - partial OpenSSL binding for Haskell
libghc-hsopenssl-doc - partial OpenSSL binding for Haskell; documentation
libghc-hsopenssl-prof - partial OpenSSL binding for Haskell; profiling libraries
libghc-hsopenssl-x509-system-dev - use system's native CA certificate store with HsOpenSSL
libghc-hsopenssl-x509-system-doc - use system's native CA certificate store with HsOpenSSL; documentation
libghc-hsopenssl-x509-system-prof - use system's native CA certificate store with HsOpenSSL; profiling libraries
libghc-openssl-streams-dev - OpenSSL network support for io-streams
libghc-openssl-streams-doc - OpenSSL network support for io-streams; documentation
libghc-openssl-streams-prof - OpenSSL network support for io-streams; profiling libraries
libghc-sha-dev - Haskell SHA suite of message digest functions
libghc-sha-doc - Haskell SHA suite of message digest functions; documentation
libghc-sha-prof - Haskell SHA suite of message digest functions; profiling libraries
libglobus-gsi-openssl-error-dbg - Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Error Handling Debug Symbols
libglobus-gsi-openssl-error-dev - Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Error Handling Development Files
libglobus-gsi-openssl-error-doc - Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Error Handling Documentation Files
libglobus-gsi-openssl-error0 - Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Error Handling
libglobus-openssl-module-dbg - Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Module Wrapper Debug Symbols
libglobus-openssl-module-dev - Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Module Wrapper Development Files
libglobus-openssl-module-doc - Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Module Wrapper Documentation Files
libglobus-openssl-module0 - Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Module Wrapper
libgnutls-openssl27 - GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
libgnutls28-dev - GNU TLS library - development files
libjs-jsencrypt - RSA Encryption in JavaScript
libjs-strophe - Library for writing XMPP clients
liblwt-ocaml-doc - cooperative light-weight thread library (documentation)
liblwt-ssl-ocaml - cooperative OpenSSL bindings for OCaml (runtime)
liblwt-ssl-ocaml-dev - cooperative OpenSSL bindings for OCaml
libneon27 - HTTP and WebDAV client library
libnetty-tcnative-java - Tomcat native fork for Netty
libnetty-tcnative-jni - Tomcat native fork for Netty (JNI library)
libnot-yet-commons-ssl-java - Not-yet-commons-SSL is a library to make SSL in Java easier
libnot-yet-commons-ssl-java-doc - Documentation for Not-yet-commons-SSL
libphp7.0-embed - HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)
libpion-5.0 - lightweight HTTP interface library - runtime files
libpion-dev - lightweight HTTP interface library - development files
libpion-doc - lightweight HTTP interface library - documentation
libpion-plugins - lightweight HTTP interface library - plugins
libpoe-filter-ssl-perl - module to make SSL in POE easy and flexible
libshadowsocks-libev-dev - lightweight and secure socks5 proxy (development files)
libshadowsocks-libev2 - lightweight and secure socks5 proxy (shared library)
libsqlcipher-dev - SQLCipher development files
libsqlcipher0 - SQLCipher shared library
libsqlcipher0-dbg - SQLCipher debugging symbols
libssh-4 - tiny C SSH library (OpenSSL flavor)
libssh-dev - tiny C SSH library. Development files (OpenSSL flavor)
libssl-dev - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
libssl-doc - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development documentation
libssl-ocaml - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL (runtime)
libssl-ocaml-dev - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL
libssl1.0-dev - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
libssl1.0.2 - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
libssl1.1 - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
libstrongswan-standard-plugins - strongSwan utility and crypto library (standard plugins)
libtcnative-1 - Tomcat native library using the Apache Portable Runtime
libwolfssl-dev - Development files for the wolfSSL encryption library
libwolfssl3 - wolfSSL encryption library
libxmlsec1-openssl - Openssl engine for the XML security library
lua-luaossl - OpenSSL bindings for Lua
lua-luaossl-dev - OpenSSL bindings for Lua (development package)
lua-openssl - OpenSSL bindings for Lua
lua-openssl-dev - OpenSSL bindings for Lua (development package)
mcrypt - Replacement for old unix crypt(1)
nagios-plugins-contrib - Plugins for nagios compatible monitoring systems
node-crypto-cacerts - updates SSL certificate chain to use a directory of certificates
openssl - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
openssl-blacklist - Blacklists for  OpenSSL RSA keys and tools
openssl-blacklist-extra - Non-default blacklists of OpenSSL RSA keys
openvpn - virtual private network daemon
perl-openssl-defaults - version compatibility baseline for Perl OpenSSL packages
php7.0-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
php7.0-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
php7.0-fpm - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
php7.0-phpdbg - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (PHPDBG binary)
puppet-module-camptocamp-openssl - Puppet module for managing openssl configuration
pyca - Certification Authority written in Python
python-m2crypto - Python wrapper for the OpenSSL library
python-ndg-httpsclient - enhanced HTTPS support for httplib and urllib2 using PyOpenSSL for Python2
python-openssl - Python 2 wrapper around the OpenSSL library
python-openssl-doc - Python wrapper around the OpenSSL library (documentation package)
python-pyelliptic - High level Python wrapper for OpenSSL (Python 2)
python-service-identity - Service identity verification for pyOpenSSL (Python 2 module)
python-socksipychain - Python SOCKS/HTTP/SSL chaining proxy module
python-tlslite - a pure Python SSL/TLS library
python3-ndg-httpsclient - enhanced HTTPS support for httplib and urllib2 using PyOpenSSL for Python3
python3-openssl - Python 3 wrapper around the OpenSSL library
python3-pyelliptic - High level Python wrapper for OpenSSL (Python 3)
python3-service-identity - Service identity verification for pyOpenSSL (Python 3 module)
r-cran-digest - GNU R package for 'hash digest' of R data structures
r-cran-openssl - GNU R toolkit for encryption, signatures and certificates based on OpenSSL
ruby-encryptor - wrapper for the standard Ruby OpenSSL library
scrypt - File encryption utility using scrypt for key derivation
shadowsocks-libev - lightweight and secure socks5 proxy
shellinabox - publish command line shell through AJAX interface
sqlcipher - Command line interface for SQLCipher
ssl-cert - simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL
stone - TCP/IP packet repeater in the application layer
tcl-tls - TLS OpenSSL extension to Tcl
tinyca - simple graphical program for certification authority management
```